# Input hour:minute:second

Tags: python

I need to input hour(1-23)(requires a colon input)minute(0-59)(colon input required)second(0-59). error message needs to be printed if the numbers are invalid, also if the colon is not between the hour and minute, and minute and second.
When a correct time is input the time should be displayed as ex: `14:07:28`
then ex: Time with colons removed: `140728`
Here is what I have done:

```
   time = input("Enter time [hh:mm:ss]:")
       if time[0:2] not in 0-23:
           print("Invalid hour")
       elif time[2] != ':':
           print("Must separate hour, minute and second with colons")
       elif time[3:5] not in 0-59:
           print("invalid minute input")
       elif time[5] != ':':
           print("Must separate hour, minute and second with colons")
       elif time[6:8] not in 0-59:
           print("Invalid second input")
       else:
           print(time[0:2,3:5,6:8])
```

this is the error message i get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Projects/Lab10CSC121/Lab10P3.py", line 2, in 
    if time[0:2] not in 0-23:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: we dont do that here you need to learn about your task, dont wait others do it for you

Comment: fair enough. I am just having a hard time getting started with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to learn about `split`

```
x ="12:32:34"
y = [int(t) for x.split(":")]
```

then you can check the length of y and if it isn't 3 complain about the format. Also, It is nice to get `y` definition in try-except block, so if `int` convergence fails you can print out some error message.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's the core of your problem.  You can handle the validation:

```
hour = 14
minute = 7
second = 28

print('{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hour, minute, second))
```